# For loop_python

Tags: python, loops

I don't know why such an easy syntax result in mistake. Can anyone help me to see if I missed out any?

This part only tries to check if a particular (num) is prime or not.
Not sure why my check_primes(10) results into 'PRIME'. Cuz I'm looping through y from 3,4,5,6,...,9-> then 10%5==0, I suppose it returns true and 'Non PRIME' is the result.

Do I do any wrong in my loop?

```
def check_primes(num):

for y in range(3,num):
        if num%y==0:
            return 'Non PRIME'
        else:
            return 'PRIME'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please double-check that your code here is indented the same as the code you are running.

Comment: Your loop executes only one time; it always returns based solely on whether the number is divisible by 3, no further check can possibly be reached.

Comment: @jasonharper, should I add while break then?

Comment: don't return, `print` instead! this way your loop will not break

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on how to debug your code.

Comment: @vincentshiusun `return` will always break a loop. Therefore, this loop will always run once.

Comment: double check the results and you'll see why: `return '%d PRIME' % y`. after the first iteration the loop checks `10%3==0` which is `False` so `else` returns `PRIME`

Answer (score 1):

A way to return 'PRIME' or 'Non PRIME' as in your example:

```
def check_primes(num):
    is_prime = True
    for y in range(3,num):
        if num % y==0:
            return 'Non PRIME'
        else:
            continue
    return 'PRIME'
```

You will return 'Non PRIME' the moment you can verify the number is not prime. Alternatively if you succeed in all your checks, you will return 'PRIME' as desired.

(Note that this is not a very efficient way to get primes)

(Note also that the comment below is correct, this method works exactly the same way with or without the else clause)

Comment: The `else` clause is not necessary.

Comment: I left the `else` clause in an effort to demonstrate more directly what would make his example work. Maybe it makes the answer less clear, but I think for someone newer to this kind of thing it could just as easily go the other way.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of "prime" states that a number is prime if and only if it is only divisible by 1 and itself. This means that a number is **not** prime if you find **one** number from `2` to `n-1` which divides `n`. To check that a number **is** prime, you must check **every** number from `2` to `n-1`. Your code stops immediately after testing divisibility by 3 in both cases.

Comment: Only need to check from 2 to floor(sqrt(n)).

Comment: @jarmod That is a very good optimization. I think for someone learning to code  that implementing a naive algorithm directly from the definition of "prime number" is a good learning experience and will help them understand the benefits of optimizations such as this.

Answer (score -1):

You should use `print` instead of return. You are breaking your loop when you return it.

Comment: Just replacing `return` with `print` will not solve the problem. The function needs to `return` something in order to be correct.